# How to replace a commit with another one in Git rebase?

Tags: git, git-rebase

Say I'm working on a feature in a branch `oldFeature`. I've done commits `A` and `B1` and sent it for the code review. In `B1` I changed some existing files but also added `newfile.txt`.

In the meantime I started working in a branch `newFeature`, forked from `oldFeature` (`HEAD` == `B1`). I've added `C`, `D`, `E`.

Meanwhile, I got code review results and had to amend `B1`, changing `newfile.txt`, and also changing some existing files. After the fixes, it became `B2`.

So to illustrate it:

```
newFeature   oldFeature
A             A
B1            B2 [B1 with some fixes]
C
D
E
```

Now I'm in `newFeature` and I want to rebase `newFeature` to have `B2` instead of `B1`. When I simply do the rebase, I have rebase a conflict due to `newfile.txt` being added in both parts of the rebase.

I want to keep the version from `oldFeature` (`B2`).

I can't move `B1` to the `HEAD`, because `C`, `D`, `E` depend on it.

I know I can do the following workaround:

- [`git checkout --theirs`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823692/resolving-a-both-added-merge-conflict-in-git)
- `git add`
- continue rebase

Then I'll have a situation like this:

```
newFeature   oldFeature
A             A
B2            B2
BX
C
D
E
```

where `BX` is more or less `B2\B1` on the files that existed in `A`.
Now I can do interactive rebase and remove `BX`.

However my workaround is kind of convoluted. Is there a simpler way to do it? By simpler I mean, that I either have

```
newFeature   oldFeature
A             A
B2            B2
B2\B1
C
D
E
```

without any rebase conflicts, and then I can get rid of that `B2\B1` commit, or to replace them automatically so I get

```
newFeature   oldFeature
A             A
B2            B2
C
D
E
```

Using Git 1.8.0.

Comment: you've perfectly described the same problem I had, thanks ^^

Comment: because `git checkout --theirs` throws an error **fatal: '--ours/--theirs' cannot be used with switching branches**, i find this oneliner to checkout all changes using **theirs** policy and add them to git: `git status | grep modified | awk '{$1=$2=$3=""}1' | xargs -I {} sh -c 'git checkout --theirs {}; git add {}'` quite useful :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could do a [rebase interactive](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/git-interactive-rebase-squash-amend-rewriting-history#interactive-rebase):

```
git checkout new_feature
git rebase --interactive old_feature
```

and drop `B1`: you simply delete the line with B1:

```
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST
```

Comment: Hmm that was easier than I thought :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I made a small script in case you don't want to do an interactive rebase :

```
COMMIT_HASH_TO_REPLACE=$1
NEW_COMMIT_HASH=$2
GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR="sed -i -re 's/^pick $COMMIT_HASH_TO_REPLACE/pick $NEW_COMMIT_HASH/'" git rebase -i --reapply-cherry-picks $COMMIT_HASH_TO_REPLACE~
```

It is a little bit faster, because you just need to run this small command if you want to replace `c6e9cdb4` by `558332c` :

```
replace c6e9cdb4 558332c
```

Comment: Can you explain what the --reapply-cherry-picks parameter is for?