# git rebase fails: Understanding the state of my repository

Tags: git

When rebasing `my_branch` on `other_branch`, i.e.:

```
git rebase other_branch
```

if there is a conflict, I get the markers

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
stuff_1
=====
stuff_2
>>>>>>> Some commit message
```

**Q1** First question: Is `stuff_1` from `my_branch` or from `other_branch` ?

I also notice that, when this happens, my `HEAD` now points to some unnamed commit, in my case `65c47727a2500691233cfed2a2cfe7686b7fb92d` (which is the output of `cat .git/HEAD`)

I also get:

```
> git status
rebase in progress; onto e41e19d
You are currently rebasing branch 'my_branch" on 'e41e19d'
...
Unmerged paths:
both added: some_file.sh
```

**Q2** While I fix the rebase, why does my `HEAD` point to some random commit?

**Q3** What does `Unmerged paths` and `both added` mean in this context??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the beginning of the rebasing process, `HEAD` is set to `other_branch`. [That is documented](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase). Then, all commits of `other_branch..my_branch` are reapplied one by one. That iterative process can fail at some point, and then you have to resolve the merge conflict, and do `git rebase --continue` once you have resolved the conflict.

**Answer to Q2:** While you are resolving the conflict, your `HEAD` points to a commit that corresponds to the last commit of `other_branch..my_branch` that was successfully applied. You can recognize using `git show`, but of course its hash is different, because its parents are different.

**Answer to Q1:** `stuff_1` is from `HEAD`. Given why I said in the answer to Q2, it means that it is from the modified version of `other_branch` where commits from `my_branch` may have already been applied.

**Answer to Q3:** *Unmerged paths* means that there are still unresolved conflicts. It seems that both `my_branch` and `other_branch` have added a new file `some_file.sh`. See the question "[Resolving a 'both added' merge conflict in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823692/resolving-a-both-added-merge-conflict-in-git)" for ways to resolve that conflict. Once you have resolved the conflict (fixing up `some_file.sh` here), you do `git add some_file.sh`, and `git rebase --continue` once you have fixed them all. `git-rebase` will commit the current change, and go on with the rebasing process.

Comment: "Unmerged paths" means that there are still unresolved conflicts. Once you have resolved the conflict (fixing up `some_file.sh` here), you do `git add some_file.sh` and `git rebase --continue` once you have fixed them all.

Comment: Thanks @lrineau. Conceptually speaking, why is adding (staging) the file after resolving the conflicts enough? Why don't I need to commit the file as well?

Comment: @user815423426: the commit is done by `git rebase --continue`.