# Git stash didn't save file

Tags: git

I've a git issue that I've not read anywhere so please explain this to me.
Let's say both me and a co-worker starts working from commit A. At this point file X wasn't exist. Both me and my co-worker have created the file without knowing. He pushed a few, so we were standing at commit E. I've tried to git pull, but OFC it told me that my local files would be overwritten, I should stash then. OK, I've used git stash, tried to pull again. Git said there are local conflicts showing that file called X and that therefore it can't pull. Ok, I've git stash poped back, made a commit. Then I've pulled and the git automerge told me that it is going to merge the conflicts. OK, at the end the file X had the content what I've pushed, and my co-workers work was gone permanently.

So what happened? I've somehow overwritten the file on the server or what? How is that even possible?

Comment: Did you resolve the merge conflict before that final commit after the stash pop? If not, that might be the problem - you may have created a commit which effectively undid everything your co-worker did because that would have been resolved during the conflict resolution. Check your commit logs and see if that's what happened.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823692/resolving-a-both-added-merge-conflict-in-git)?

Comment: Piece back together the correct file by checking out your partner's version.

Comment: Don't Panic(tm). Whatever happened, I'm sure your co-worker's changes are not gone permanently. They are still in the remote repo, to say the least.

Comment: No panic here. Already got the file back, but the even still conserns me. Why didn't the `git stash` command stashed the files so I could pull the new files?

Answer (score 2):

#### MVCE would help

It would help if you showed, step by step, *exactly* what you did, or—even better—provided a minimal, complete, verifiable example (also known as an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).  Of course, the point of your question is that you don't know quite how you did this in the first place.  But the thing is, *we* don't either!  We can only *guess*.

My guess is that you never `git add`ed the file in the first place.  Let's look at *my* MVCE.  I start by making a one-commit repository with a `master` branch, with just a README file.  (These commit messages are terrible, by the way.)

```
$ mkdir tt; cd tt
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in ...
$ echo demo failure to save file in stash > README
$ git add README
$ git commit -m initial
[master (root-commit) 0442487] initial
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 README
```

Now let's make your co-worker's branch, which you would eventually bring into your repository as `origin/master`.  We can't make a remote-tracking branch this way (I could do it by cheating) so let's just use a regular branch:

```
$ git checkout -b other
Switched to a new branch 'other'
$ echo new file X > X
$ git add X
$ git commit -m 'new file X on branch other'
[other 37681f5] new file X on branch other
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 X
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
```

Now we are ready to go back to you being yourself.  Let's make a new file and fail to `git add` it.  Let's also modify `README`: we'll need this to make `git stash` do anything.  We can `git add` the `README` change, or not `git add` it, whichever we prefer; this part will make no difference.

```
$ echo our new file X is different from his > X
$ echo 'add extra line to readme' >> README
```

You now ran `git pull` and got a complaint.  We literally *can't* run `git pull` here, but we don't have to: all `git pull` does is run `git fetch` to get commits from your upstream remote, and then run `git merge` to merge those commits into your current branch.  I always recommend that those new to Git avoid `git pull`: it's full of traps for the unwary, and you will have more problems than if you just use the two separate commands yourself.

So, we'll do the two-separate-commands thing.  But: we do not (we *can* not) `git fetch` your wo-worker's commit in this example, which is why we made a branch named `other` above in the first place.  So we just go right to the *second* command, `git merge`:

```
$ git merge other
Updating 0442487..37681f5
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    X
Please move or remove them before you merge.
Aborting
```

(Note, by the way, that when you run `git pull`, it effectively runs `git merge origin/master`, rather than `git merge other`.  We are using `other` here because *we* made this, rather than getting it through `git fetch`.)

#### What stash does, and doesn't do

We have now reached the stage at which you ran `git stash`.  Had you run `git status` first, you would have seen this, which might have been a clue, though it's hard to know at first what parts of this deserve what amounts of attention:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   README

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    X

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

The two interesting bits of information here are that we have a modified, but not yet staged, `README`, and—this is more important for our `git stash` step—the *untracked* file `X`.

Anyway, let's run `git stash` (which means `git stash save`) now:

```
$ git stash
Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: 0442487 initial
HEAD is now at 0442487 initial
```

Let's take a look at `git status` now (I am guessing you did not—this is a mistake; you should check `git status` frequently):

```
$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    X

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

There's that pesky `X` still!  The point here is that `git stash save` *doesn't* save untracked files by default.  (You can get it to do so, but if you had, that would have been even worse.  Don't do this until you truly understand merging and merge issues: you'll get yourself into a huge trap that can only be resolved by understanding merge issues.  This is yet another reason to avoid `git pull`: if you learn to use `git merge` directly, you will be on your way to understanding merges and the occasional problem.)

Now let's simulate `git pull` again.  Once again we must skip the fetch step and go straight to `git merge`:

```
$ git merge other
Updating 0442487..37681f5
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    X
Please move or remove them before you merge.
Aborting
```

And here we have it: `git stash` failed to help.

Let's try undoing the existing stash (which will put `README` back into the modified-but-not-added mode) and then `git add X`.  Normally I recommend using `git stash apply` first, *checking the result carefully*, and then using `git stash drop` *only if you are happy with that result*, but we'll just run `git stash pop`, which means `git stash apply && git stash drop`:

```
$ git stash pop
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   README

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    X

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
Dropped refs/stash@{0} (1e7d19ea701fcc3dd8e0157c9a8a8555f74316a4)
```

#### Enough about `git stash`!  Let's go on to normal commits and merging...

Now we'll `git add` the two files and commit, rather than stashing:

```
$ git add README X
$ git commit -m 'created file X'
[master 699e149] created file X
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 X
```

*Now* we can merge.  (Or, we could fetch-and-merge, via `pull`, if we had a remote.  But there's nothing new to fetch, and we don't have a remote.  And besides, it's time to learn how merges work!  So let's just merge.)  We will get an *add/add conflict:*

```
$ git merge other
Auto-merging X
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in X
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Again, in your own case, you would be doing `git merge origin/master`—or just plain `git merge`, which uses your current branch's *upstream* setting, which is presumably `origin/master`.  But one way or another, we now have this "add/add conflict".

#### Resolving conflicts

When Git stops a merge with a conflict, it means Git doesn't know what to do.  *You* must help it out here.  You can run `git status` to see how far Git got:

```
$ git status
On branch master
You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")
  (use "git merge --abort" to abort the merge)

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

    both added:      X

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Git has left, in our work-tree, the file `X`.  But there are *two* files named `X`: ours, and your co-workers (which we're simulating as `other`).  Which one did Git leave us?  Here's what is in X:

```
$ cat X
<<<<<<< HEAD
our new file X is different from his
||||||| merged common ancestors
=======
new file X
>>>>>>> other
```

So, the answer is that it left *both* versions of `X` in the work-tree.  (I have `merge.conflictStyle` set to `diff3` so mine shows "merged common ancestors" here.  If you have the default `merge.conflictStyle` setting, Git won't show that part.  Since there are no common ancestors, that part is empty anyway—it's not really useful here.  It's only useful when there *are* common ancestors, during a *modify/modify conflict*.)

It's now your job to come up with a merged version of `X`, or perhaps separate out the two versions into two different files.  Precisely what you want, and how you want to do it, is up to you.  Let's say we'd like to rename *our* `X` to something else, and extract *their* (your co-worker's) `X` intact:

```
$ git show HEAD:X > X.ours
$ git checkout --theirs X
$ cat X.ours
our new file X is different from his
$ cat X
new file X
```

Now `git status` will show the new untracked file `X.ours`, as well as the conflicted file.  Let's `git add` both the adjusted `X` (back to his version only) and the new `X.ours`:

```
$ git add X.ours X
$ git status
On branch master
All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.
  (use "git commit" to conclude merge)

Changes to be committed:

    modified:   X
    new file:   X.ours
```

Since we're now ready to commit, we can conclude the merge now with `git commit`.

(This is an example of *correctly* resolving the add/add conflict.  I note that you say that this is not what happened; but I don't know what you *did* do, and without more information, I can't even guess what that was.  I've been concentrating, above, on what `git stash` *can't* do: it cannot help with add/add conflicts, and it does not save untracked files by default.)

Answer (score 0):

First thing, When you have used `git stash save`, After the command it should have no modified files available, and then if you have `git pull`ed your branch, then the conflicts should not be available / happen. Hence I am saying your firstever `git stash save` did not worked successfully.

Second, if after you have `git pull`ed your branch successfully, the work of your co-worker has auto-merged with your branch, which should be available.

Kindly check your `git log` via :

```
git log --name-status
```

then, Check your code difference via :

```
git show <<Commit ID>>
```

whether your requierd code is available, or not.

Comment: "... I am saying your firstever git stash save did not worked successfully."  
  
Yes, I'm aware of it and I'm asking what could have made this. Even tho I was using `git stash`, not git `git stash save`    
  
Log:  
commit A - from me (created file X)  
from A - commit B - by co-worker  
from B - commit C - by co-worker (created fileX)  
from C - commit D - by co-worker  
from D - commit E - by co-worker  
from A - commit F - by me  
Auto merge by me  
from AutoMerge - commit G - by me  
.....etc  
  
So it looks normal, somewhy stash wasn't working. But why couldn't it?