# If I `git rm <file>` when I get a 'both added' conflict, will that remove the file from my branch or the whole repo?

Tags: git

Here's the situation:

I created a few files to get some other code in my branch working. This was just a quick-fix - at the same time a co-worker also created and worked on these files. Thus, when I merge my code I get a `both added` message for these files.

I want abandon my version of the files - I don't want to push them up.

Would using `git rm <file>` on these remove my version of the files or delete the files from the repo/project altogether?

What's the best way I can handle this (I've read about ours/theirs but it makes no sense to me)?

Comment: [This seems to be an exact answer to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823692/resolving-a-both-added-merge-conflict-in-git), but I won't mark this as duplicate.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes I did see that one. To be honest, I do not understand the terminology used in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Since you want to abandon your version of the file, you want:

```
git checkout --theirs <file>
git add <file>
```

This tells Git that the correct resolution of combining your work (create a new version of *file*) and their work (create a *different* new version of *file*) is to use their version of the file.

#### Long, but please do read it

Given that Git's terminology is a problem (and it is, for a lot of people), what you should probably do here is learn the terminology.  So let's take a look at that.

First, though, don't think about your repository as holding *files*.  It does, but thinking about it this way won't get you anywhere—it's like trying to think about your house as holding outlets and doorknobs and so on.  That's the wrong level to think about it.  Your house contains *rooms*, and it's the rooms that have the doors that have the doorknobs, and the outlets that you plug appliances and your phone charger into, and so on.  Just as the interesting level of "house" is "rooms", the interesting level of *repository* is *commits*.  (Unlike a house—well, any *practical* house anyway—you just keep adding new commits to a repository, more or less forever, without ever throwing away *any* old ones.  Well, mostly!  It's hard to truly get rid of commits, but it can be done.)

So, your repository holds a big collection of commits.  Each commit holds some files, and we'll get to that in a moment, but the repository itself is about the commits.

Most commits are pretty simple: they have a collection of files—a source tree snapshot—and some metadata, such as "this commit was made by A. U. Thor <thor@example.com>".  One of the key pieces of metadata that almost every commit has is the *hash ID* of its *parent* commit.  That's the commit that was there before Mr Thor (or whoever) made a new one.  (Think of it as the door into the previous room, for instance.)  So a commit:

- has some metadata—some extra information that's not part of the files *in* the commit; plus
- a complete snapshot of every file.

Git *finds* a commit by its *hash ID*, which is that big ugly seemingly-random thing that `git log` prints:

```
$ git log
commit 3e5524907b43337e82a24afbc822078daf7a868f
Author: Junio C Hamano <...
```

These hash IDs are the true names of each commit.  Every commit gets a unique one.  They're quite useless to most humans, but Git uses them to find all the data that goes with each commit.  This particular commit's parent is `e66e8f9be8af90671b85a758b62610bd1162de2d`, so this commit—this `3e5524907...` says, in part, `my parent is e668ef9be8...`.  (One's eyes tend to glaze over when looking at these big ugly IDs.  Fortunately, as humans, we can *mostly* ignore them.)

When you run `git checkout somebranch`, what Git does is turn the branch name into a hash ID, and then extract all the files from that commit so that you can use them or work on them.  It also sets its idea of the *current commit* to whatever that hash ID is, and sets its idea of the *current branch name* to the name you gave it.  Running `git status` will tell you `on branch somebranch`, so now you are "on" that branch—which in part means that you have some particular commit hash ID checked out.

Now that you have some commit checked out, as you work within your repository, what you are doing is deciding what goes into some files that you will commit.  Once you make each new commit, you will freeze *all* the files into that commit forever, as a new snapshot, in that form.  If you *remove* a file and make a commit, you make a new commit / snapshot that has one fewer files, without changing any of the previous commits.

Git makes these snapshots from its *staging area*, which it also calls its *index*, or sometimes its *cache*.  These are just three names for the same thing, either because it's so important (which it is) or because the first name that Linus used, "index", was such a bad name (in my opinion, it's not great but it's not really that bad).  This staging area is normally almost invisible: you don't ever actually look at it directly.  Instead, you do your work in what Git calls your *work-tree* or *working tree* or *working directory*.  In this area, files are just files—they're not weird special Git entities.

In the index / staging-area, and in commits, files are weird and special: mostly, they're compressed to save space.  In commits, they're also read-only: you cannot change any existing commit, not even one bit.  You can overwrite the file that's in the index, by using `git add` to copy the ordinary file from your work-tree area.  That's how you get your changes done: you work on the file in the work-tree, then run `git add file`.

Once you have all the files the way you want, and have copied them into the staging area to overwrite the previous copies, you run `git commit` to have Git make a new commit.  Git freezes the index copies of all the files—including the ones you *didn't* overwrite—and puts them all into the new commit.  You are the author of the new commit.  The new commit's *parent commit* is the commit you extracted earlier, by running `git checkout`.

The same holds true when you are resolving a *merge conflict*.  What you are doing is deciding *which files, with which contents, will go into the next commit*.  But there are a few things that are special during this time.

The first is that the next commit you make will be a *merge commit*, which is to say, a commit with *more than one parent*.  Instead of just saying *my one parent is <big ugly ID>*, it will say: *my two parents are <first big ugly ID> and <second big ugly ID>*.  Git uses this internally to know that this was in fact a merge, and to be able to follow the history of the commits down *both* authors: your work, and whoever else's work, get combined at the merge, and *you* decide what the combined result is, but Git records for posterity the fact that *both* of your commits fed into it.

The second special thing that happens during this conflicted merge is that the index—remember, this is the staging area, the place where you're building your next merge commit to make—expands!  Normally, your index holds just *one copy* of each file.  But when you're merging, your index holds up to *three* copies of each conflicted file!  You can have three `README.md` files simultaneously.  (I'll assume here that the conflict is about `README.md`.  Probably the file has some other name, but it all works the same.)

Technically, these multiple versions are called *higher stage* entries.  Mostly you don't have to care about this; you just have to care about whether your index has this state for some file(s).

Your work-tree can't pull off this "multiple versions of one file" trick, and your eventual *commit* can only have one `README.md` in it too.  So this special index state, where it has more than one file, is something *you* have to fix.  When you are done merging `README.md`, you have the choice of having *one* `README.md` in the index, or having *no* `README.md` in the index.  Whichever choice you make, when you run `git commit`, Git will freeze that into the new commit.

This is what the linked question and answer is about.  The index holds *both* versions of the file: yours and theirs.  You can:

- Use the work-tree to create a correct or combined file, and `git add` the result.  This overwrites all the conflicting multiple versions of `README.md`, so that the index has just one `README.md`.
- Use `git checkout --ours` to extract your version of `README.md` from the index into the work-tree.  The index still has all the versions, but now the work-tree file is *your* version.
- Use `git checkout --theirs` to extract their version of `README.md` form the index into the work-tree.  As before, the index still has all the versions, but now the work-tree file is *their* version.

  If you choose one of these two `git checkout` options, you can then go back to the first option—`git add`—to copy the work-tree file, which is now just one of the two, into the index, wiping out the other versions.
- Or, you can run `git rm` on the file.  This removes *all* the versions from the index, so now the index has *no* `README.md`.  If you are done resolving all conflicts, you can now `git commit`; this new commit has no `README.md`.  As we already saw, this doesn't affect *any* previous commit, but it does mean that you declared that the correct way to combine *your* `README.md` and *their* `README.md` was to remove the file entirely.

  If that's the wrong answer—if you want to keep *their* version, for instance—don't do that.

In any case, once you are all done resolving all files, you simply run `git commit` as usual.  This makes the new merge commit, and then changes the *branch name itself*—the hash ID stored under the name of branch you're on, that is—so that it remembers your new commit.  That's how branches grow: a new commit has the old branch tip as its parent, or for a merge, the first one of its two parents.  The new commit's newly-generated unique ID goes into the branch name.  Hence if you had:

```
...--o--o--o   <-- yourfix (HEAD)
      \
       o--o--o   <-- origin/theirfix
```

and you ran `git merge origin/theirfix` and got a merge conflict and resolved it and committed, you end up with:

```
...--o--o--o---M   <-- yourfix (HEAD)
      \       /
       o--o--o   <-- origin/theirfix
```

Note that the new commit (labeled `M` here for Merge) is added on to your own branch name, `yourfix`, by virtue of *changing* the hash ID stored under the name `yourfix`.  Since new commit `M` remembers the hash ID that *was* stored in `yourfix` just a moment ago, Git still has every file that *was* in that commit, ready to extract if you ever want it.

And, since `M` remembers the *same* commit hash ID as `origin/theirfix`, it's now safe for you to `git push` commit `M` to the Git over at `origin`, and ask `origin` to change its own `theirfix` (which your Git is calling `origin/theirfix`) to point to `M`, as `M` remembers their previous commit too.  Git calls this a *fast-forward* operation when you run `git push`—but let's leave that terminology for other questions.

Answer (score 2):

This answer can be put together by reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25576415/what-is-the-precise-meaning-of-ours-and-theirs-in-git) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823692/resolving-a-both-added-merge-conflict-in-git).  In a Git merge, the `ours` branch usually refers to the target branch into which the merge is happening.  And `theirs` usually refers to the single branch which is being merged into the target.  Depending on whether your branch, with the versions of the newly added files you want to keep, is the target or the single branch, you would want to do one of the following after hitting the merge conflict:

```
git checkout --ours path/to/some/file
git checkout --theirs path/to/some/file
```

As you correctly pointed out, if you do `git rm <file>`, you will remove *both* versions of the file, probably not what you want.