# git pull --rebase with auto merge strategy not working

Tags: git, merge, rebase, conflict, git-pull

I am trying to pull rebase with auto merging strategy,

```
m-hissain-sk01:sc hissain$ git status
On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 47 and 3 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

error: could not apply b5f4d22... Refactored existing source
Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
"git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
Could not apply b5f4d22... Refactored existing source

m-hissain-sk01:sc hissain$ git status
interactive rebase in progress; onto 2d4593d
Last command done (1 command done):
   pick b5f4d22 Refactored existing source
Next commands to do (2 remaining commands):
   pick 4298398 Implemented clean swift version
...

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)

    added by us:     MyProj.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata
    added by us:     MyProj.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/IDEWorkspaceChecks.plist
    added by us:     MyProj/Configs/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Contents.json
        ...
```

Expected conflicts will be automatically resolved with ours version. But after running the command, I still see unstashed codes waiting to be resolved manually.

**Why didn't it work?**

Comment: There are several possible problems here. You should include the actual output of such a command, and what you expected instead (preferably cut-and-pasted text, rather than a screenshot).

Comment: Ok i will update soon

Comment: @torek I have updated the commands and outputs for convenience. Could you help to find whats wrong?

Comment: Someone marked the question for closing saying `This question does not appear to be about programming`. How come this post does not appear to be about programming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The beginning of the rebase is missing from your output, but I strongly suspect that there was a message of the form:

```
CONFLICT (add/add): ...
```

or:

```
CONFLICT (rename/delete): ...
```

in among the various other messages.  While you specified `-X ours` (according to the original question text at least):

> ```
> git pull --rebase -X ours
> ```

`-X ours` only resolves *some* conflicts automatically, not *all* conflicts.  In particular, it does not resolve what I call *high level* conflicts, such as add/add or rename/delete conflicts.

What you must do at this point is either finish the merge operation and continue the rebase using `git rebase --continue`, or abort the entire rebase operation using `git rebase --abort`.  Remember that `git pull` merely runs *two* Git commands for you:

1. `git fetch`, and then
2. (if that succeeds), `git merge` or `git rebase` with parameters determined by what was fetched in step 1.

The `git rebase` you invoked in step 2 is incomplete.  (I looked for some SO answers on how to go about resolving such merges—I know they exist—and have not found any good ones to link yet.)  Edit: here's one for add/add: [Resolving a 'both added' merge conflict in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9823692/1256452)

Comment: You are right there are add/delete operations. Thanks for the clarification.